# Resin prints pulling away from build platform

Tags: adhesion, resin, elegoo-mars

My prints start out good, but seem to warp or pull away from the build platform at a later time. Should I divide up my support bases so they're not one big base? Should I sand/roughen the build platform for better adhesion?

Printer: Elegoo Mars
Resin: Standard Grey (Elegoo)
Exposure base layers: 70 sec
Exposure elsewhere: 11 sec
Layer height: 0.05

[image: Resint print pulling away]

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell from the image, but one aspect of resin printing that you want to consider when placing a model is the cross-sectional area for each layer. You'll see prints that could be printed flat on an FFF printer being placed at an angle on a resin printer.

This orientation presents a smaller cross-section and thereby a smaller amount of force applied when the bed lifts and peels the model from the bottom of the vat.

If you have the ability within your slicer to scrub through the layers, observe the general area created by the slicer for each layer.

If you tilt the model even a few degrees from level, you'll reduce the forces involved.

It appears that you've used a "priming" layer on your bed, the initial layers of resin ostensibly provided to reduce the problem you're experiencing. That's a good start, but the rest of the model is generating enough peeling force to ruin the print.

Comment: A 45° angle, even if rather extreme, can alter the forces extremely. Note that the tilt might actually provide a larger crosssection in some orientation, if this brings more surfaces into the fire: think a 1-unit long cube that rotates around X: the crosssection on the YZ plane is $1*(\cos{\alpha}+\sin{\alpha})$, but most bodies don't behave like cubes but like rectangular blocks with different a, b, c, then the crosssection is $ab \cos{\alpha}+bc \sin{\alpha}$. part of the trick is to make the change in average crosssection somewhat steady.